# Why does my Axios post function keep returning 401?

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I am having issues with Axios Post requests whenever authentication is required. Whenever I try and run the following code I get a 401 (Unauthorized)

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
console.log(token);

const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const newPost = {
                title, body, image
            };
            await Axios.post(
                "http://localhost:5000/posts/createpost", {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type":"application/json",
                        "x-auth-token": token,
                    },
                    newPost
                }
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

And here is what the post router looks like

```
router.post("/createpost", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {title, body, img} = req.body;
        if(!body && !img) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                msg: "Please Enter a text or image"
            });
        }

        const post = new Post({
            title,
            img,
            body,
            postedBy: req.user
        });

        const savedPost = await post.save();
        res.json(savedPost)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }
});
```

And lastly here is the auth method that is being used in the router above

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
        if(!token) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                msg: "No Authentication token, Access Denied!"
            });
        }

        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        if(!verified) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                msg: "Token authrization failed, Access Denied!"
            });
        }

        req.user = verified.id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
}
```

The reason I am confused is cause when I use the Insomnia Rest client and manually enter those headers it posts fine as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxYe.png). When I remove the `auth` from the post router it works fine, so I know the issue is with authentication.

Comment: I added two lines that I omitted that show where the token is coming from, and the ```console.log(token)``` shows the same token that is being displayed in the insomnia rest client. As for the title, body, and image, they are being added manually by user input. Those work and worked when I removed authentication.

Comment: I can't see where you're calling `submit()`. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And which of the `res.status(401)` is being triggered and what are values there when it does?

Comment: Are you using any CORS middleware and if so, have you added the custom `x-auth-token` to the list of allowed request headers? Assuming these requests are coming from your browser, use the _Network_ dev tools console to check the requests / responses

Comment: @charlietfl it is the ```"No Authentication token, Access Denied!"``` message

Comment: @Phil yes, I am using CORS middleware and no I have not added the x-auth-token. Is there documentation as to how I would go about doing this? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @MagiklyDelishis never mind, the CORS middleware default is to allow all headers requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [`axios.post()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) incorrectly. It takes three arguments; `url`, `data` and `config`. You're only passing two arguments and have put the `headers` in the `data` parameter. Try this instead

```js
await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/posts/createpost", newPost, {
  headers: {
    "x-auth-token": token
  }
})
```

Note that `Content-type: application/json` is the default for Axios and can be omitted.